# Column Qualifier/Mutiple Data in same columns

Tags: sql

With SQL, is it possible to have one table that, in a column, there is information that identifies what column information comes after? For example:

```
Column1,  Column2, Column3
CustName, ID1,     Date
CustName, ID1,     Date
CustName, ID2,     PaymentType
CustName, ID2,     PaymentType
CustName, ID3,     Address
```

Could this be done with just string information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explain a bit further. What do you mean is it possible? You can of course create a table with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE customer_data
(
  customer_name varchar(255),
  customer_id varchar(255),
  data_field varchar(255),
  data_value varchar(255)
);
```

What is the purpose? Obviously if you have differing data_types for data_value you would have to convert them in a query or in code but to answer is it possible? Then yes.

Comment: It was more to see if there was a more complex way of storing the information. I'm working with a proprietary database that does my short example, and wondering what the best method for Converting it to SQL was.